# resetting player after video has played

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

wasn't able to add all the code before.  essentially after a movie plays I want the swf to reset to it's first original loading frame.

```
function stopVideo()
{
    showPlayBtn(true);
    Tweener.addTween(videocontrols.stopBtn, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    myStream.stop();
    myStream.seek(0);
    myStream.pause(true);
    if (playOnStart == "true")
    {
        if (!imgHolder.holder)
        {
            loadImage();
        }
        else
        {
            Tweener.addTween(imgHolder.bmp, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
        } // end else if
    }
    else
    {
        Tweener.addTween(imgHolder.bmp, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    } // end else if
    videocontrols.playBtn.gotoAndStop(1);
    updateInformation(true);
} // End of the function
function playVideo()
{
    if (timeOfPause && timeOfPause > 0)
    {
        if (tempVideo != myVideo)
        {
            myStream.seek(0);
        } // end if
        myStream.pause(false);
        tempVideo = myVideo;
    }
    else
    {
        if (tempVideo != myVideo)
        {
            myStream.seek(0);
        } // end if
        myStream.play(myVideo);
        tempVideo = myVideo;
    } // end else if
    Tweener.addTween(imgHolder.bmp, {_alpha: 0, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    videocontrols.playBtn.gotoAndStop(2);
    playBtn._visible = false;
} // End of the function
function startVideo()
{
    myStream.seek(0);
    myStream.play(myVideo);
    tempVideo = myVideo;
    videocontrols.playBtn.gotoAndStop(2);
    playBtn._visible = false;
}// End of the function
```

Stage.align = "TL";
Stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
setProperty("", _quality, "HIGH");
Stage.displayState = "normal";
ASVideoPlayer._visible = false;
ASVideoPlayer._width = Stage.width;
ASVideoPlayer._height = Stage.height;
playBtn._visible = false;
playBtn._alpha = 0;
videocontrols.progressMC.progressBar._width = 0;
videocontrols.progressMC.loadingBar._width = 0;
errorMC._alpha = 0;
bufferingMC._alpha = 0;
defaultVideo = _parent.defaultVideo;
image = _parent.image;
logo = _parent.logo;
logoLink = _parent.logoLink;
logoTarget = _parent.logoTarget;
playOnStart = _parent.autoplay;
startVolume = _parent.videoVolume;
fitToPlayer = true;
bufferSize = 5;
protection = false;
domain = "as-flash.com";
doubleClickEnable = true;
doubleClickTime = 250;
checkFlashPlayerVersion = true;
FlashPlayerDownloadLink = "http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/";
useKeyboardShortcuts = true;
keyVideoSeek = 5;
mouseWheelEnabled = true;
keyVideoVolume = 5;
logoX = 10;
logoY = 10;
HDbuttonX = 10;
HDbuttonY = 10;
imageLoaderX = 25;
imageLoaderY = 25;
if (!defaultVideo)
{
    defaultVideo = 1;
} // end if
if (!startVolume)
{
    startVolume = 50;
} // end if
if (!playOnStart)
{
    playOnStart = "false";
} // end if
var newConnection = new NetConnection();
newConnection.connect("");
var myStream = new NetStream(newConnection);
myStream.setBufferTime(bufferSize);
mediaDisplay.attachVideo(myStream);
if (!soundMC)
{
    this.createEmptyMovieClip("soundMC", this.getNextHighestDepth());
} // end if
soundMC.attachAudio(myStream);
var soundVolume = new Sound(soundMC);
soundVolume.setVolume(startVolume);
videocontrols.volumeMC.volBar._width = videocontrols.volumeMC.posMC._x = startVolume / 100 * videocontrols.volumeMC.backgroundMC._width;
startPlayer = function ()
{
    memPositions();
    resizePlayer();
    if (videoLinkHD.length > 3)
    {
        flashPlayerVersionCheck();
    } // end if
    if (videoLink.length > 3 && videoLinkHD.length > 3)
    {
        this.attachMovie("QualityIcon", "QualityIcon", this.getNextHighestDepth());
        QualityIcon._x = videoArea._width - QualityIcon._width - HDbuttonX;
        QualityIcon._y = HDbuttonY;
        QualityIcon.gotoAndStop(defaultVideo);
        if (defaultVideo == "1")
        {
            myVideo = videoLink;
        }
        else
        {
            myVideo = videoLinkHD;
        } // end else if
        QualityIcon.onRollOver = function ()
        {
            Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 80, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
        };
        QualityIcon.onRollOut = function ()
        {
            Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
        };
        QualityIcon.onPress = function ()
        {
            myStream.close();
            mediaDisplay.clear();
            Tweener.addTween(videocontrols.progressMC.progressBar, {_width: 0, time: 1, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
            Tweener.addTween(videocontrols.progressMC.posMC, {_x: 0, time: 1, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
            if (this._currentframe == 1)
            {
                myVideo = videoLinkHD;
                flashPlayerVersionCheck();
                this.gotoAndStop(2);
            }
            else
            {
                myVideo = videoLink;
                this.gotoAndStop(1);
            } // end else if
            tempVideo = myVideo;
            myStream.play(myVideo);
            if (videocontrols.playBtn._currentframe == 1)
            {
                myStream.seek(0);
                myStream.pause(true);
                Tweener.addTween(bufferingMC, {_alpha: 0, time: 6.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
                loadImage();
            }
            else
            {
                Tweener.addTween(bufferingMC, {_alpha: 100, time: 6.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
                myStream.seek(0);
                myStream.pause(false);
            } // end else if
            Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
        };
    } // end if
    if (playOnStart == "true")
    {
        videocontrols.playBtn.gotoAndStop(2);
        myStream.play(myVideo);
        tempVideo = myVideo;
        Tweener.addTween(bufferingMC, {_alpha: 100, time: 6.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
        updateInformation(false, "buffering");
    }
    else
    {
        updateInformation(true);
        if (image.length > 0)
        {
            loadImage();
        } // end if
        videocontrols.playBtn.gotoAndStop(1);
    } // end else if
    if (logo.length > 3)
    {
        if (!logoMC)
        {
            this.createEmptyMovieClip("logoMC", this.getNextHighestDepth());
        } // end if
        logo_loader.loadClip(logo, logoMC);
    } // end if
};
memPositions = function ()
{
    screenW = Stage.width;
    screenH = Stage.height;
    videocontrolsX = videocontrols._x;
    playBtnX = videocontrols.playBtn._x;
    playBtnY = videocontrols.playBtn._y;
    stopBtnX = videocontrols.stopBtn._x;
    stopBtnY = videocontrols.stopBtn._y;
    progressMCX = videocontrols.progressMC._x;
    progressMCY = videocontrols.progressMC._y;
    progressMCW = videocontrols.progressMC._width;
    outputMCX = Stage.width - 200;
    outputMCY = videocontrols.outputMC._y;
    volumeonoffMCX = Stage.width - 104;
    volumeonoffMCY = videocontrols.audioOnOff._y;
    volumeMCX = Stage.width - 89;
    volumeMCY = videocontrols.volumeMC._y;
    volumeMCW = videocontrols.volumeMC._width;
    fitToPlayerBtnX = Stage.width - 31;
    fitToPlayerBtnY = videocontrols.fitToPlayerBtn._y;
    fullscreenBtnX = Stage.width - 13;
    fullscreenBtnY = videocontrols.fullscreenBtn._y;
    videocontrols.progressMC.backgroundMC._width = Stage.width - videocontrols.progressMC._x - (Stage.width - videocontrols.outputMC._x) - 15;
    videocontrols.progressMC.loadingBar._width = pctLoaded * videocontrols.progressMC.backgroundMC._width;
    videocontrols.progressMC.outlineMC._width = videocontrols.progressMC.backgroundMC._width * 1.005000E+000;
};
myStream.onStatus = function (status)
{
    errorMC._alpha = 0;
    if (status.code == "NetStream.Play.Start")
    {
        preloadVideo();
        playingVideo = true;
        updateInformation(true);
        resizeVideo();
    } // end if
    if (status.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop")
    {
        Tweener.addTween(imgHolder.bmp, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
        playingVideo = false;
        updateInformation(false);
        progressMC.progressBar._width = 0;
    } // end if
    if (status.code == "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound" || status.code == "NetStream.Play.FileStructureInvalid" || status.code == "NetStream.Play.NoSupportedTrackFound")
    {
        playingVideo = false;
        progressMC.progressBar._width = 0;
        videocontrols.playBtn.gotoAndStop(1);
        errorMC._alpha = 100;
        Tweener.addTween(bufferingMC, {_alpha: 0, time: 6.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    } // end if
    if (status.code == "NetStream.Buffer.Empty")
    {
        Tweener.addTween(bufferingMC, {_alpha: 100, time: 6.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    } // end if
    if (status.code == "NetStream.Buffer.Full")
    {
        Tweener.addTween(bufferingMC, {_alpha: 0, time: 6.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
        updateInformation(true);
    } // end if
    if (status.code == "NetStream.Seek.Notify")
    {
    } // end if
    if (status.code == "NetStream.Seek.InvalidTime")
    {
    } // end if
};
myStream.onMetaData = function (obj)
{
    videoDuration = obj.duration;
};
preloadVideo = function ()
{
    if (!preloaderMC)
    {
        this.createEmptyMovieClip("preloaderMC", this.getNextHighestDepth());
    } // end if
    preloaderMC.onEnterFrame = function ()
    {
        pctLoaded = myStream.bytesLoaded / myStream.bytesTotal;
        videocontrols.progressMC.loadingBar._width = pctLoaded * videocontrols.progressMC._width - 1;
        if (pctLoaded >= 1)
        {
            pctLoaded = 1;
            videocontrols.progressMC.loadingBar._width = videocontrols.progressMC.backgroundMC._width;
            delete preloaderMC.onEnterFrame;
        } // end if
    };
};
updateInformation = function (stat, msg)
{
    clearInterval(updateInterval);
    if (myStream.time >= 0)
    {
        resizeVideo();
    } // end if
    if (stat == true)
    {
        this.onEnterFrame = function ()
        {
            videocontrols.progressMC.progressBar._width = videocontrols.progressMC.posMC._x = myStream.time / videoDuration * videocontrols.progressMC._width;
            if (!msg)
            {
                videocontrols.outputMC.outputTF.text = outputTime(myStream.time, videoDuration);
            }
            else
            {
                videocontrols.outputMC.outputTF.text = msg;
            } // end else if
            if (Math.round(myStream.time) == Math.round(videoDuration))
            {
                videocontrols.playBtn.gotoAndStop(1);
                Tweener.addTween(imgHolder.bmp, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
                showPlayBtn(true);
                timeOfPause = 0;
                myStream.seek(0);
                myStream.pause(true);
                videocontrols.outputMC.outputTF.text = outputTime(timeOfPause, videoDuration);
                videocontrols.progressMC.progressBar._width = 0;
                delete this.onEnterFrame;
            } // end if
        };
    }
    else if (msg)
    {
        outputMC.outputTF.text = msg;
    }
    else
    {
        outputMC.outputTF.text = "";
    } // end else if
};
outputTime = function (curTime, totTime)
{
    curMinutes = Math.floor(curTime / 60);
    curSeconds = Math.floor(curTime % 60);
    totMinutes = Math.floor(totTime / 60);
    totSeconds = Math.floor(totTime % 60);
    if (!totMinutes || totMinutes == undefined)
    {
        totMinutes = 0;
    } // end if
    if (!totSeconds || totSeconds == undefined)
    {
        totSeconds = 0;
    } // end if
    if (curMinutes < 10)
    {
        curMinutes = "0" + curMinutes;
    } // end if
    if (curSeconds < 10)
    {
        curSeconds = "0" + curSeconds;
    } // end if
    if (totMinutes < 10)
    {
        totMinutes = "0" + totMinutes;
    } // end if
    if (totSeconds < 10)
    {
        totSeconds = "0" + totSeconds;
    } // end if
    return (curMinutes + ":" + curSeconds + " / " + totMinutes + ":" + totSeconds);
};
videocontrols.playBtn.onRollOver = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 70, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    if (this._currentframe == 1)
    {
        updateInformation(true, "PLAY");
    }
    else
    {
        updateInformation(true, "PAUSE");
    } // end else if
};
videocontrols.playBtn.onRollOut = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    updateInformation(true);
};
videocontrols.playBtn.onPress = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    if (this._currentframe == 1)
    {
        showPlayBtn(false);
        if (timeOfPause && timeOfPause > 0)
        {
            myStream.pause(false);
        }
        else
        {
            if (tempVideo != myVideo)
            {
                myStream.seek(0);
            } // end if
            myStream.play(myVideo);
            tempVideo = myVideo;
        } // end else if
        this.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    else
    {
        showPlayBtn(true);
        timeOfPause = myStream.time;
        myStream.pause(true);
        Tweener.addTween(bufferingMC, {_alpha: 100, time: 6.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
        this.gotoAndStop(1);

```
    var trackingURL = "";


    var trackInfo = new LoadVars();
    trackInfo.value1 = myVideo;
    trackInfo.value2 = "";


    var myDate = new Date();
    trackInfo.sendAndLoad(trackingURL + "?cacheKiller=" + (myDate.UTC), (trackInfo), "POST");
} // end else if
Tweener.addTween(imgHolder.bmp, {_alpha: 0, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
updateInformation(true);

var trackingURL = "";


    var trackInfo = new LoadVars();
    trackInfo.value1 = myVideo;
    trackInfo.value2 = "";


    var myDate = new Date();
    trackInfo.sendAndLoad(trackingURL + "?cacheKiller=" + (myDate.UTC), (trackInfo), "POST");
```

};
videocontrols.stopBtn.onRollOver = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 70, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    updateInformation(true, "STOP");
};
videocontrols.stopBtn.onRollOut = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    updateInformation(true);
};
videocontrols.stopBtn.onPress = function ()
{
    stopVideo();
};
videocontrols.fullscreenBtn.onRollOver = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 70, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    if (this._currentframe == 1)
    {
        updateInformation(true, "fullscreen");
    }
    else
    {
        updateInformation(true, "normal screen");
    } // end else if
};
videocontrols.fullscreenBtn.onRollOut = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    updateInformation(true);
};
videocontrols.fullscreenBtn.onPress = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    ratio = mediaDisplay.width / mediaDisplay.height;
    if (this._currentframe == 1)
    {
        Stage.displayState = "fullScreen";
        this.gotoAndStop(2);
        videoArea._width = Stage.width;
        videoArea._height = ASVideoPlayer._height - videocontrols._height;
        videoArea._x = videoArea._y = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Stage.displayState = "normal";
        videoArea._width = Stage.width;
        videoArea._height = ASVideoPlayer._height - videocontrols._height;
        videoArea._x = videoArea._y = 0;
        this.gotoAndStop(1);
    } // end else if
    updateInformation(true);
    resizeVideo();
    resizePlayer();
    var trackingURL = "";

```
    var trackInfo = new LoadVars();
    trackInfo.value1 = myVideo;
    trackInfo.value2 = "";


    var myDate = new Date();
    trackInfo.sendAndLoad(trackingURL + "?cacheKiller=" + (myDate.UTC), (trackInfo), "POST");
```

};
videocontrols.fitToPlayerBtn.onRollOver = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 70, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    if (this._currentframe == 1)
    {
        updateInformation(true, "fit to player");
    }
    else
    {
        updateInformation(true, "original size");
    } // end else if
};
videocontrols.fitToPlayerBtn.onRollOut = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    updateInformation(true);
};
videocontrols.fitToPlayerBtn.onPress = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    if (fitToPlayer == false)
    {
        fitToPlayer = true;
        this.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    else
    {
        fitToPlayer = false;
        this.gotoAndStop(1);
    } // end else if
    updateInformation(true);
    resizeVideo();
};
videocontrols.progressMC.backgroundMC.onRollOver = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 70, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    updateInformation(true, "seek video");
};
videocontrols.progressMC.backgroundMC.onRollOut = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    updateInformation(true);
};
videocontrols.progressMC.backgroundMC.onPress = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 70, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    updateInformation(true);
    myStream.pause(true);
    this.onEnterFrame = function ()
    {
        if (this._parent._xmouse >= 0 && this._parent._xmouse <= this._width)
        {
            seekingTime = this._parent._xmouse / this._width * videoDuration;
            videocontrols.progressMC.progressBar._width = seekingTime / videoDuration * videocontrols.progressMC._width;
            myStream.seek(seekingTime);
            if (seekingTime == videoDuration)
            {
                myStream.pause(true);
            } // end if
        } // end if
    };
};
videocontrols.progressMC.backgroundMC.onRelease = videocontrols.progressMC.backgroundMC.onReleaseOutside = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    if (videocontrols.playBtn._currentframe == 1)
    {
        myStream.pause(true);
    }
    else
    {
        myStream.pause(false);
    } // end else if
    timeOfPause = myStream.time;
    updateInformation(true);
    delete this.onEnterFrame;
};
videocontrols.volumeMC.backgroundMC.onRollOver = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 70, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    updateInformation(true, "adjust volume");
};
videocontrols.volumeMC.backgroundMC.onRollOut = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    updateInformation(true);
};
videocontrols.volumeMC.backgroundMC.onPress = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 70, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    this.onEnterFrame = function ()
    {
        if (this._xmouse >= 0 && this._xmouse <= this._width)
        {
            seekingVolume = this._xmouse / this._width * 100;
            videocontrols.volumeMC.volBar._width = videocontrols.volumeMC.posMC._x = this._xmouse;
            soundVolume.setVolume(seekingVolume);
            dispTF = "volume: " + Math.round(seekingVolume) + " %";
            updateInformation(true, dispTF);
            if (seekingVolume == 0)
            {
                videocontrols.audioOnOff.gotoAndStop(2);
            }
            else
            {
                videocontrols.audioOnOff.gotoAndStop(1);
            } // end if
        } // end else if
    };
};
videocontrols.volumeMC.backgroundMC.onRelease = videocontrols.volumeMC.backgroundMC.onReleaseOutside = function ()
{
    Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    updateInformation(true);
    delete this.onEnterFrame;
};
updateVolumePosition = function ()
{
    videocontrols.volumeMC.posMC._x = videocontrols.volumeMC.volBar._width;
    soundVolume.setVolume(videocontrols.volumeMC.volBar._width / videocontrols.volumeMC.backgroundMC._width * 100);
};
if (useKeyboardShortcuts == true)
{
    keylistener = new Object();
    keylistener.onKeyDown = function ()
    {
        clearInterval(updateInterval);
        if (Key.isDown(13))
        {
            if (Stage.displayState == "normal")
            {
                Stage.displayState = "fullScreen";
                ASVideoPlayer._width = Stage.width;
                ASVideoPlayer._height = Stage.height;
                videocontrols.fullscreenBtn.gotoAndStop(2);
            }
            else
            {
                Stage.displayState = "normal";
                ASVideoPlayer._width = screenW;
                ASVideoPlayer._height = screenH;
                videocontrols.fullscreenBtn.gotoAndStop(1);
            } // end if
        } // end else if
        if (Key.isDown(27))
        {
            Stage.displayState = "normal";
            ASVideoPlayer._width = screenW;
            ASVideoPlayer._height = screenH;
            videocontrols.fullscreenBtn.gotoAndStop(1);
        } // end if
        if (Key.isDown(32))
        {
            if (videocontrols.playBtn._currentframe == 1)
            {
                showPlayBtn(false);
                if (timeOfPause && timeOfPause > 0)
                {
                    myStream.pause(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    myStream.play(myVideo);
                } // end else if
                videocontrols.playBtn.gotoAndStop(2);
            }
            else
            {
                showPlayBtn(true);
                timeOfPause = myStream.time;
                myStream.pause(true);
                videocontrols.playBtn.gotoAndStop(1);
            } // end if
        } // end else if
        if (Key.isDown(39))
        {
            gotoTime = myStream.time + keyVideoSeek;
            if (gotoTime < videoDuration)
            {
                myStream.seek(gotoTime);
            }
            else
            {
                myStream.seek(videoDuration);
            } // end if
        } // end else if
        if (Key.isDown(37))
        {
            gotoTime = myStream.time - keyVideoSeek;
            if (gotoTime > 0)
            {
                myStream.seek(gotoTime);
            }
            else
            {
                myStream.seek(0);
            } // end if
        } // end else if
        if (Key.isDown(38))
        {
            gotoVolume = videocontrols.volumeMC.volBar._width / videocontrols.volumeMC.backgroundMC._width * 100 + keyVideoVolume;
            videocontrols.audioOnOff.gotoAndStop(1);
            if (gotoVolume < 100)
            {
                videocontrols.volumeMC.volBar._width = videocontrols.volumeMC.posMC._x = gotoVolume / 100 * videocontrols.volumeMC.backgroundMC._width;
                soundVolume.setVolume(gotoVolume);
            }
            else
            {
                gotoVolume = 100;
                videocontrols.volumeMC.volBar._width = videocontrols.volumeMC.posMC._x = videocontrols.volumeMC.backgroundMC._width;
                soundVolume.setVolume(100);
            } // end else if
            dispTF = "volume: " + Math.round(gotoVolume) + " %";
            updateInformation(true, dispTF);
        } // end if
        if (Key.isDown(40))
        {
            gotoVolume = videocontrols.volumeMC.volBar._width / videocontrols.volumeMC.backgroundMC._width * 100 - keyVideoVolume;
            if (gotoVolume > 0)
            {
                videocontrols.volumeMC.volBar._width = videocontrols.volumeMC.posMC._x = gotoVolume / 100 * videocontrols.volumeMC.backgroundMC._width;
                soundVolume.setVolume(gotoVolume);
            }
            else
            {
                gotoVolume = 0;
                videocontrols.volumeMC.volBar._width = videocontrols.volumeMC.posMC._x = 0;
                videocontrols.audioOnOff.gotoAndStop(2);
                soundVolume.setVolume(0);
            } // end else if
            dispTF = "volume: " + Math.round(gotoVolume) + " %";
            updateInformation(true, dispTF);
        } // end if
        updateInterval = setInterval(update, 1000);
    };
    Key.addListener(keylistener);
} // end if
update = function ()
{
    updateInformation(true);
};

videocontrols.onEnterFrame = function ()
{
    resizeVideo();
    resizePlayer();
    resizeImage();
};
flashPlayerVersionCheck = function ()
{
    if (checkFlashPlayerVersion == true)
    {
        var _loc4 = System.capabilities.version;
        var _loc3 = _loc4.split(" ");
        var _loc2 = _loc3[1].split(",");
        if (_loc2[0] >= 10)
        {
            HDsupport = true;
        }
        else if (_loc2[0] >= 9 && _loc2[1] >= 0 && _loc2[2] >= 115 && _loc2[3] >= 0)
        {
            HDsupport = true;
        }
        else
        {
            HDsupport = false;
        } // end else if
        if (HDsupport == false)
        {
            errorMC._alpha = 0;
            bufferingMC._alpha = 0;
            if (!downloadWindow)
            {
                this.attachMovie("downloadWindow", "downloadWindow", this.getNextHighestDepth());
            } // end if
            downloadWindow._x = videoArea._width / 2;
            downloadWindow._y = videoArea._height / 2;
            downloadWindow.closeBtn.onRollOver = downloadWindow.downloadBtn.onRollOver = function ()
            {
                Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 40, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
            };
            downloadWindow.closeBtn.onRollOut = downloadWindow.downloadBtn.onRollOut = function ()
            {
                Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
            };
            downloadWindow.closeBtn.onRelease = downloadWindow.closeBtn.onReleaseOutside = function ()
            {
                Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
                downloadWindow.removeMovieClip();
            };
            downloadWindow.downloadBtn.onRelease = downloadWindow.downloadBtn.onReleaseOutside = function ()
            {
                Tweener.addTween(this, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
                getURL(FlashPlayerDownloadLink, "_blank");
                downloadWindow.removeMovieClip();
            };
        } // end if
    } // end if
};
loadImage = function ()
{
    if (!imgHolder.holder)
    {
        imgHolder.createEmptyMovieClip("holder", imgHolder.getNextHighestDepth());
    } // end if
    if (!imgHolder.bmp)
    {
        imgHolder.createEmptyMovieClip("bmp", imgHolder.getNextHighestDepth());
    } // end if
    imgHolder.holder._visible = false;
    imgHolder.bmp._visible = false;
    image_loader.loadClip(image, imgHolder.holder);
};
showPlayBtn = function (stat)
{
    if (stat == true)
    {
        playBtn._visible = true;
        playBtn._alpha = 0;
        playBtn._xscale = playBtn._yscale = 130;
        Tweener.addTween(playBtn, {_alpha: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
        Tweener.addTween(playBtn, {_xscale: 100, _yscale: 100, time: 4.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    }
    else
    {
        playBtn._visible = false;
        playBtn._alpha = 0;
    } // end else if
    playBtn.onRollOver = function ()
    {
        this._alpha = 80;
    };
    playBtn.onRollOut = function ()
    {
        this._alpha = 100;
    };
    playBtn.onPress = function ()
    {
        playVideo();
    };
};
if (protection == true)
{
    protocol = _url.substr(0, _url.indexOf(":"));
    if (protocol == "file")
    {
        startPlayer();
    }
    else if (_url.indexOf(domain) > 0)
    {
        startPlayer();
    }
    else
    {
        videocontrols._visible = false;
        myStream.close();
        this.attachMovie("protectionMC", "protectionMC", this.getNextHighestDepth());
        protectionMC._alpha = 0;
        protectionMC._x = Stage.width / 2;
        protectionMC._y = Stage.height / 2;
        Tweener.addTween(protectionMC, {_alpha: 100, time: 6.000000E-001, transition: "easeOutCubic"});
    } // end else if
}
else
{
    startPlayer();
} // end else if

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing what's on the timeline of the Movieclip it's really hard to tell. I'm also slightly unclear what you mean by loading default? The playhead and the loader should minimize to width 0, or a whole host of variables should be reset.

Anyway, these two lines (you probably already figured this one out) are what you need

```
videocontrols.progressMC.progressBar._width = 0;
videocontrols.progressMC.loadingBar._width = 0;
```

They seem to be lines 73 and 74. I couldn't find any functions that are called as the video is playing, or when the video ends. If there are any then stick a call to those in there. If there aren't then add one. The status handler you're looking for is `NetStream.onStatus` ([link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00002009.html))